# Error: Unknown property, Visualforce custom controller

Tags: controller, salesforce, apex, visualforce, markup

Trying to fetch data from a REST endpoint, store the data as a list of my_obj class, return this list and present it as a Table using Visualforce controller.

Apex Class 1:

```
public class api{
    List<String> rec_ids = new List<String>();
    List<String> last_calls = new List<String>();
    List<String> messages = new List<String>();
    List<my_obj> final_res = new List<my_obj>();
public List<my_obj> getfinal_res(){
        // --------getting all the required data-----
        // storing as a list of my_obj
        for(Integer i=0;i<last_calls.size();i++){
            my_obj obj = new my_obj(rec_ids[i], last_calls[i], messages[i]);
            System.debug(obj.rec_id);
            final_res.add(obj);          
        }
        return final_res;
    }
}
```

Apex Class 2:

```
global class my_obj{
    public String rec_id, msg, last_call;
    public my_obj(String rec_id, String msg, String last_call){
        this.rec_id = rec_id;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.last_call = last_call;
    }
}
```

Visualforce Controller:

```
<apex:page controller="telog_api">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!final_res}" /> -->
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!final_res}" var="a">
          <apex:column value="{!a.rec_id}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!a.msg}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!a.last_call}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This line `<apex:outputText value="{!final_res}" />` works fine. Displays the list of the objects. But I want to display it as a table. On doing that getting this error: "Error: Unknown property 'my_obj.rec_id;"

Answer (score 1):

This is because the following variable are not declared as property:

public String rec_id, msg, last_call;

These should be declared as follows:

```
`public String rec_id {get;}
public String msg {get;}
public String last_call {get;}`
```

get; will make sure that these variables are visible on the above VisualForce page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer: 
Change `public String rec_id, msg, last_call;` to

```
    public String rec_id {get;set;}
    public String msg {get;set;}
    public String last_call {get;set;}
```